# Red5 can't locate Java on Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, red5

I'm setting up a Red5 server on Cygwin

I get this

```
/usr/share/red5$ sh red5.sh
Running on  CYGWIN_NT-6.1-WOW64
Unable to locate Java. Please set JAVA_HOME environment variable.
```

However, I can also do this:
    `javac -version` and get `javac 1.7.0`, so I know that's installed, at least.

I can also go into the emacs `.bash_profile` and see that I've added this to the bottom:

```
export PS1='\w\$ '
export EMACS_HOME=~/emacs-22.3
export JAVA_HOME =/cydrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_32
export PATH=$PATH:$EMACS_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$EMACS_HOME/bin
```

So what's missing?

---

I edited `.bash_profile` to be this:

```
export PS1='\w\$ '
export EMACS_HOME=~/emacs-22.3
export JAVA_HOME=/cydrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/
export JAVA_HOME=$( cygpath -d "$JAVA_HOME" )
export PATH=$PATH:$EMACS_HOME/bin:$JAVA_HOME/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$EMACS_HOME/bin
```

And I get this error

```
cygpath: cannot create short name of D:\cygwin\cydrive\c\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_32\
```

Comment: I've seen Java hiccup with paths with spaces in the past. Any chance things get better if you convert the JAVA_HOME path from unix style to DOS style (which has no spaces) using this command... `export JAVA_HOME=$( cygpath -d "$JAVA_HOME" )`, and then trying to run the red5.sh script again?

Comment: @Costa, could you please elaborate on this? Do you mean to replace the `export JAVA_HOME` with that line? Wouldn't I actually lose the file-path to the jdk, if that was the case?

Comment: Indeed, the command I put above would need to have been run *after* the export you already have in your .bash_profile. I just put it like that to make your test easier. If it works, you then would either have to add the command as is right under your existing export of JAVA_HOME, or you could just modify the export to put the DOS-style path directly.

Comment: @Costa So when I implement that I get new error. I'll update my question

Comment: The new error has to do with how cygpath itself works, it's not really related to your original problem. You can remove it from your question again. Instead, let's try putting the DOS-style path in manually... remove the line you added and instead change the export you already had to `export JAVA_HOME="C:\PROGRA~1\JAVA\JDK16~1.0_3"`. (You can confirm that's actually the right path by doing `ls "C:\PROGRA~1\JAVA\JDK16~1.0_3"` first. It should at least list the files in the right folder.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`export JAVA_HOME=/cydrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_32/`

I just misspelled `cydrive`, when it should have been `cygdrive`.

Comment: That would also explain why `cygpath` failed to convert it correctly too. :)